# In Java, do referenced libraries get fully included in the exported jar?

Tags: java, compilation, build-dependencies

If I had a library with 3 classes that I included in my java build path as an external lib and it was composed of:

ClassA:

```
public class ClassA {
    public String getData() {
        return ClassB.useThis();
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class ClassB {
    public static String useThis() {
        return "I'm class B.";
    }
}
```

Class C:

```
public class ClassC {
    public int someMethod() {
        // Some irrelevant stuff
    }
}
```

And then in my project I did:

```
System.out.println(new ClassA().getData());
```

And then exported this as a runnable jar, would Class C be included in this jar regardless of the fact that it's not referenced in any of the other classes or even used?

This has pondered my mind as you see libraries in C++ that are more than 10mb yet the exported executable that uses that library is substantially smaller. So, is this the same case for java?

Comment: No, this doesn't happen with Java by default.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - "by default" - so is there any way to force it to only include references library classes in the exported jar file?

Comment: Sounds like this is an IDE question.

Comment: @immibis this doesn't depend on IDE.

Comment: @immibis - it probably is. Unless of course javac has an argument you can pass to achieve this. If not, maybe I'll have to ask on the eclipse forums since iirc they have their own custom javac or something.

Comment: I would recommend reading all the answers in the question, not only the accepted one.

Comment: @user3530525 The `javac` command doesn't build JAR files.

Comment: @EJP - Woops, you're right. My mistake. "jar.exe"

Comment: I'm not sure how I suggest a duplicate for my own thread but this seems to be my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518400/generate-minimized-jar-with-only-used-classes

Comment: I guess that I'll need to use third party, post compilation optimization tools such as ProGuard to strip away unused classes.